# Why does "Remove this item when it is no longer applied'' in Drive Maps preferences disconnect users' AD home folder?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, mappeddrive

When I enable "Remove this item when it is no longer applied" for any mapped drive in Group Policy preferences, the user's home folder that is mapped by their Active Directory account attributes gets disconnected. Why is this happening?

This is how I map drives through GPO preferences:
[image]

This is how I setup home folders for users in AD Users and Computers:
[image]

Using "Remove this item when it is no longer applied" here for any of GPO mapped drives:
[image]

Results in the home folder being unmounted.

Why?

Comment: What are you setting in Item-level targeting? Are there any other GPOs that might be mapping a drive to U: or any other GPOs (or logon script) that might be re-mapping the home folder?

Comment: In Item-level targeting I set global security groups that contain users. There are no other GPO for mapping drives or logon script that might re-mapping the home folder